# Save string to text file in C++

Tags: c++-cli

I have an error and I can not get solved ...

I want to build a configuration string together and save to text file. But I always get an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException ".
besides how can I override if the text file already exists.

Thank You

The function looks like this:

```C++
             // get dialog title
             String^ s = this->groupBox1->Text;
             std::string dialogName = marshal_as<std::string>(s);
             const char * dialogTitle = dialogName.c_str();

             // get list mit DBC Dateinamen
             int numberOfDbcFile = listView1->Items->Count;
             std::string nameStr = "";

             for(int i =0; i< numberOfDbcFile;i++)
             {
                 System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  listViewItem = this->listView1->Items[i];
                 String^ fileNr = listViewItem->SubItems[0]->Text;
                 String^ fileName = listViewItem->SubItems[1]->Text;
                 String^ filePath = listViewItem->SubItems[2]->Text;
                 nameStr += marshal_as<std::string>(fileNr)+" ";
                 nameStr += marshal_as<std::string>(fileName)+" ";
                 nameStr += marshal_as<std::string>(filePath)+"\n";
             }

             char *fileList = new char(strlen(nameStr.c_str()) +1);
             /*strcpy(fileList, nameStr.c_str());*/
             if(fileList == NULL){
                 /*throw bad_alloc();*/
                 cerr << "Fehler" << endl;
                 exit(1);
                 /*strcpy(fileList, nameStr.c_str());*/
           } else {
                 /*fileList = NULL;*/ 
                 strcpy(fileList, nameStr.c_str());
             }
             // get length of list
             int lengthOflist = sizeof(fileList);  

             // get cfg string
             int checkList = listView2->Items->Count;
             int checkList3 = listView3->Items->Count;
             int a = 0;
             std::string cfgS = "";
             for(int i =0; i< checkList;i++)
             {
                 if(listView2->Items[i]->Checked && listView2->Items[i]->Selected == true)
                 {
                    String^ dbc =  label2->Text;
                    cfgS += "#" + marshal_as<std::string>(dbc) + bo_name +"\n";
                    System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  listViewItem = this->listView2->Items[i];
                    String^ boid = listViewItem->SubItems[0]->Text;
                    String^ bolaenge = listViewItem->SubItems[2]->Text;
                    String^ boN = listViewItem->SubItems[1]->Text;
                    String^ bokom = textBox1->Text;
                    std::string boStr = "@" + marshal_as<std::string>(boid)+":";
                    boStr += marshal_as<std::string>(bolaenge)+":";
                    boStr += marshal_as<std::string>(boN)+":";
                    boStr += "'"+ marshal_as<std::string>(bokom)+"'"+"\n";
                    cfgS += boStr;
                    a++;
                    for(int j =0; j< checkList3;j++)
                    {
                         if(listView3->Items[j]->Checked)
                         {
                            System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  listViewItem = this->listView3->Items[j];
                            String^ sgName = listViewItem->SubItems[0]->Text;
                            String^ sgBit = listViewItem->SubItems[1]->Text;
                            String^ sgLaenge = listViewItem->SubItems[2]->Text;
                            String^ sgFaktor = listViewItem->SubItems[3]->Text;
                            String^ sgOffset = listViewItem->SubItems[4]->Text;
                            String^ sgMin = listViewItem->SubItems[5]->Text;
                            String^ sgMax = listViewItem->SubItems[6]->Text;
                            String^ sgEinheit = listViewItem->SubItems[7]->Text;
                            String^ sgkom = Kommentar->Text;
                            std::string sgStr = "|"+ marshal_as<std::string>(sgName)+":";
                            sgStr += marshal_as<std::string>(sgBit)+":";
                            sgStr += marshal_as<std::string>(sgLaenge)+":";
                            sgStr += marshal_as<std::string>(sgFaktor)+":";
                            sgStr += marshal_as<std::string>(sgOffset)+":";
                            sgStr += marshal_as<std::string>(sgMin)+":";
                            sgStr += marshal_as<std::string>(sgMax)+":";
                            sgStr += marshal_as<std::string>(sgEinheit) + ":";
                            sgStr += "'"+ marshal_as<std::string>(sgkom)+"'"+"\n";
                            cfgS += sgStr;
                         }
                    }
                 }  
             }


             cfgS += "##";


             char *cfgString = new char(strlen(cfgS.c_str()) +1);
             if(cfgString == NULL){
                 cerr << "Fehler" << endl;
                 exit(1);
                 /*throw bad_alloc();*/

           } else {
                 /*cfgString = NULL; */
                 strcpy(cfgString, cfgS.c_str());
             }
             // get cfg string length
             int lengthOfString = sizeof(cfgString);
             // get max number of selected BO
             maxNumOfSelection = a;

             // call configuration function
            int32_t result = m_OpenBusConfigurationDialog->openBusConfigurationDialog(
                    dialogTitle,fileList, lengthOflist,cfgString,lengthOfString, maxNumOfSelection);

            ofstream fichier("C:\\Users\\akoudjou\\Desktop\\CAN Import\\Test2\\test.txt",ios::out); 
              if(fichier.is_open()){
             fichier << fileList << endl;
             fichier << cfgString << endl;
             fichier.close();
              }
              else{
                  cout << "Datei konnte nicht geöffnet werden" << endl;
              }
             exit(0);

         }
```

Comment: This looks very different from what my C++ looks like.

Comment: This is a lot of code and it isn't clear if the problem you're having is writing a string to a file or  a different problem before you even get to that point.  You might want to try and clean up the example and question to clearly highlight the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the error you are experiencing, but it is definitely an error.

```
char *fileList = new char(strlen(nameStr.c_str()) +1);
```

That allocates a single char, initializing it with an integer value equal to the length of `nameStr` + 1. But you actually are using it as an array, so initialize it as such, using square brackets:

```
char *fileList = new char[strlen(nameStr.c_str()) +1];
                      // ^                          ^
                      // |     Square brackets      |
```

And you do it again later:

```
char *cfgString = new char(strlen(cfgS.c_str()) +1);
```